# Why convert in ImageMagick can not convert pdf to image

Tags: windows-10, pdf, conversion, imagemagick

I try to convert pdf file to png image in ImageMagick from windows 10 command line as follows:

```
Magick convert a.pdf a.png
```

I get error

```
magick: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe" -q ...
```

But it works for converting image to image. What is the problem?

Comment: If you give the full path to where you installed the ImageMagick version of `convert` it should work, but it may need other programs from the same directory: if so, and this directory is not in `PATH`, you will need to go to that directory and give full paths to the source and target files instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ImageMagick needs [Ghostscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript) installed in order to read PDF files.

Ghostscript is a separate project entirely. `gswin32c` is the 32-bit MS-Windows version of Ghostscript.